# linking promises, or one promise triggers another

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I'm building a weather app where I first have to get the users location, then make the request to get the weather.

So I have a `GeolocationService` and a `WeatherService`. My `WeatherService` is currently calling the `Geolocation` Service. How do I make the `WeatherService` wait until it has the results from the `GeolocationService` before making the HTTP request?

```
  app.factory('GeolocationService',function($q,$window,$rootScope){
        return {
            getLatLon: function(){
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                if(!window.navigator){
                    $rootScope.$apply(function(){
                        deferred.reject(new Error("Geolocation not available"));
                    });
                } else {
                    $window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
                        $rootScope.$apply(function(){
                            deferred.resolve(position);
                        });
                    }, function(error){
                        $rootScope.$apply(function(){
                            deferred.reject(error);
                        });
                    });
                }

                return deferred.promise;
            }
        };
    });

    app.factory("WeatherService", function ($q,$http,$rootScope, GeolocationService) {
        return {
            getWeather: function(){
                var weather;
                var loc = new GeolocationService.getLatLon(); 
                var  lat= loc.lat || 37.4568202221774, 
                lon= loc.lon || -122.201366838789 ;
                var units = '';
                var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?lat='+lat+'&lon='+lon+'&units='+units+'&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
                $http.jsonp(url)
                    .success(function(data) {
                        weather=data;
                        return weather;
                    })
                    .error(function(err){
                        weather=err;
                        return err;
                    });
            }

        };
    });
```

Comment: really don't think you need to wrap resolve and reject in `$apply`, not sure what the thinking is there

Comment: @charlietfl - I've tried without wrapping the resolve in $apply, but the .then isn't being triggered without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use the promise in your service and then chaine the promise. For sample I have a user with user.company_id and if I want get the name of the company I have to wait that the user is load. It the same that your situation.

this is my service:

```
    angular.module('UserService', []) 
.factory('UserService', function($q , $http, $rootScope,$timeout) {
var currentUserPromise = null;
var currentCompanyPromise = null;
return {
    getCurrentUser: function() {
        if (currentUserPromise === null) {
            var config = {};
            config.cache = true;
            config.method = "GET"; 
            config.url = "users/get_current_user";
            currentUserPromise = $http(config)
                .then(function(response) {
                    if (typeof response.data === 'object') {
                        return response.data.user;
                    } else {
                        // invalid response
                        return $q.reject(response.data);
                    }  
                }, function(response) {
                    // something went wrong
                    return $q.reject(response.data);
                });
        }
        return currentUserPromise;
    },

    getCurrentCompany: function(company_id) {
        if (currentCompanyPromise === null){
            var config = {};
            var company = {};
            company.id = company_id; 
            config.cache = true;
            config.method = "GET"; 
            config.url = "/companies/show";
            config.params = company;
            currentCompanyPromise = $http(config)
                .then(function(response) {
                    if (typeof response.data === 'object') {
                        return response.data.company;
                    } else {
                        // invalid response
                        return $q.reject(response.data);
                    }

                }, function(response) {
                    // something went wrong
                    return $q.reject(response.data);
                });
            }
            return currentCompanyPromise;

        }
    };     
});
```

and in my controller I user this like this:

CONTROLLER :

```
var promiseCurrentUser = UserService.getCurrentUser();
promiseCurrentUser.then(function(user) {
    $scope.currentUser = user;
    UserService.getCurrentCompany(user.company_id).then(function(company){
        $scope.companyName = company.name;
    });
});
```

And What is cool with the promise is that it is resolve once.

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Your `GeolocationService`'s function `getLatLon` is returning a promise. There is no need to call it with a `new` operator.

Your `getWeather` function should look something along the lines of:

```js
app.factory("WeatherService", function ($q,$http,$rootScope, GeolocationService) {
    return {
        getWeather: function(){
            var weather;
            return GeolocationService.getLatLon().then(
                function (loc) {
                    var  lat= loc.lat || 37.4568202221774, 
                    lon= loc.lon || -122.201366838789 ;
                    var units = '';
                    var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?lat='+lat+'&lon='+lon+'&units='+units+'&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
                    return $http.jsonp(url)
                        .success(function(data) {
                            weather=data;
                            return weather;
                        })
                        .error(function(err){
                            weather=err;
                            return err;
                        });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Here, we first call the `GeolocationService.getLatLon()` to get a promise. Then we chain our processing as a chain to it. The success function will get the `position` you resolve it with here `deferred.resolve(position);`.

Also, you do not need to wrap the `resolve` and `reject` within an `$apply`. Hence, your `GeoLocationService` can be simplified to:

```js
            if(!window.navigator){
                deferred.reject(new Error("Geolocation not available"));
            } else {
                $window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
                        deferred.resolve(position);
                }, function(error){
                        deferred.reject(error);
                });
            }
```

Comment: thanks @musically_ut, without wrapping the deferred, the .then is not getting triggered. Also,returning `weather` from the success statement isn't passing the `weather` to the scope. My scope is just `$scope.weather = WeatherModel.getWeather();`

Comment: Which version of angular are you using? The latest version (1.2) [makes promises A+ compliant](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/3699) and they _should_ fire without requiring an extra `$digest` loop. The `weather` _is_ passed to the scope, but as a promise. If any of your operations depend on the value of `weather`, include them in a chain: `$scope.weather.then(function (weatherData) { ... })`. Or assign `weather` in a `then: `WeatherModel.getWeather().then(function (weatherData) { $scope.weather = weatherData; })`. Both of these are _async_, though.

Comment: That explains it, I'm using v 1.5, hoping to upgrade in an upcoming release. I tried your suggestion of chaining 'then', but get an error 'cannot call method then of undefined anonymous function`.

Comment: Just tested it again, I definitely have the `()` in the call.